# How to insert a keyline between 3rd and 4th list item, but be the width of the parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a keyline between two list items with class names using nth-child and after. The trick here is that the list items are ~250px wide, float:left and I want the keyline to extend the width of the parent div that is 1000px wide, after the third list item. So far I have been able to create the keyline after the third list item, but it's width remains 250px wide:

```css
    #FS-TilesContainer {
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }
    
    .FS-Tile {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 225px;
        margin: 0 0 47px 35px;
    }
    
    .FS-Tile:nth-child(-n+3) {
        width: 300px;   
    }
    
    .FS-Tile:nth-child(3)::after {
        content:'';
        border-top: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
        display: block;
        width: 1000px;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="FS-TilesContainer">
         <ul id="FS-TilesGrid">
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
            <li class="FS-Tile"></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see in this code.

You need to give `position:absolute` in this code

```
.FS-Tile:nth-child(3)::after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute; //new added
}
```

Check this hope it will helpful to you.

```css
#FS-TilesContainer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

.FS-Tile {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 221px;
    margin: 0 0 47px 35px;
}

.FS-Tile:nth-child(-n+3) {
    width: 300px;   
}

.FS-Tile:nth-child(3)::after {
    content:'';
    border-top: 5px solid #EAEAEA;
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="FS-TilesContainer">
     <ul id="FS-TilesGrid">
        <li class="FS-Tile">test</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test1</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test2</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test3</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test4</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test5</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test6</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test7</li>
        <li class="FS-Tile">test8</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```